# Identifier resolution and simple assignment

Tags: javascript

Let we have a simple script:

```
obj=new String('str');//1
obj.length;//2
```

At line 1 we have a simple assignment which evaluated as follows:

1. Evaluate PrimaryExpression: Identifier (`obj` in my case). `(undefined, obj, false)` will be returned as result.
2. Evaluate NewExpression `new String('str');`. Denote result of evalution by `rref`
3. `GetValue(rref)`
4. Putting value getting at step 3 to reference getting at step 1.
5. Return result of step 4.

At this line `obj-->'str'` bindings doesnt add to environment record of any execution contex. But when `obj` `PrimaryExpression:Identifier` will be evaluated as `('str', obj, false)` type Refernce and we can get property of `'str'` by this reference.

**Question:**

Why `PrimaryExpression:Identifier` `obj` at line 2 will be evaluated as `('str', obj, false)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unusual sort of question for SO, but interesting nonetheless.

The answer to your question is that it gets added to the global execution context (assuming this script is the whole program).

See the [ecma spec section regarding Programs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-14).

Step 3 sets up an execution context for global code, and it's this context in which `obj` is initially referenced, and which the `PutValue` operation sets the binding of in your step 4 above.

Comment: Exactly, `PutValue(V,W)` where `IsUnresolvedReference(V)` returns `true` added property to global object with `GetReferencedValue(V)` as property name and `W` as value. Environment record of global object is Object Environment record, hence adding properties to `global` adding a corresponding binding. I hope, my understanding is correct now.